# How to Specify Type=Text OR Type=Text Area in a Selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following which iterates a function across all textboxes (type="text"):

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {//blah};)
```

How do I specify the selector so it iterates that function across all textboxes and textareas on the page?

Something like the following?

```
$('input[type="text" || type="textarea"]').each(function () {//blah});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

input doesn't have a type "textarea". There is a separate textarea element so you would use

```
$('input[type=text], textarea')
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I was just about to mention that, +1

Comment: Awesome, thanks.   Worked like a charm - had tried the comma, and thought it was the problem.  Completely forgot that input does not have a textarea type.